# Не могу понять в чём ошибка: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

Tags: c++, visual-studio

У меня в **DATE.hpp** код:

```
#ifndef DATE_HPP
#define DATE_HPP

class DATE {
unsigned short day_;
unsigned short month_;
unsigned short year_;

public:
DATE();
DATE(unsigned short day, unsigned short month, unsigned short year);
DATE(DATE const & other);
~DATE();
void print();
void set();
};

#endif
```

В **DATE.cpp**:

```
#include "DATE.hpp"
#include <iostream>

DATE::DATE()
:day_{ 0 }, month_{ 0 }, year_{ 0 } {}

DATE::DATE(unsigned short day, unsigned short month, unsigned short year)
: day_{ day }, month_{ month }, year_{ year } {}

DATE::DATE(DATE const & other)
: day_{ other.day_ }, month_{ other.month_ }, year_{ other.year_ } {}

void DATE::print() {
std::cout << day_ << "." << month_ << "." << year_ << std::endl;
}

void DATE::set() {
std::cout << "\nSetting_DATE:\n";
std::cout << "day: ";
std::cin >> day_;
std::cout << "month: ";
std::cin >> month_;
std::cout << "year: ";
std::cin >> year_;
}

DATE::~DATE() {}
```

У меня выдают 2 ошибки. Не могу исправить, подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить.

[image: Файлы .cpp и .hpp]
[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Где у вас точка входа? Она отсутствует. Функция `main` или `WinMain`.

Comment: Спасибо! И правда как я могла не заметить важную функцию main.

Answer (score 3):

Нужна точка входа, `int main()`, `int` можно заменить на любой другой тип.

Comment: "*int можно заменить на любой другой тип.*" - стандарт С++ имеет другое мнение...